# Is it possible to use a function in an SQLAlchemy filter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that checks an object for some properties and returns boolean values depending on the result. It's too complex to write it in filter, but it works and returns the right value.

Now I want to use sqlalchemy to return all objects that this function returns True for. I tried:

```
DBSession.query(MyObject).filter(self.check_attributes(MyObject) == True).all()
```

and

```
DBSession.query(MyObject).filter(self.check_attributes(MyObject)).all()
```

Both failed to select the right objects. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the function that is easy to write, but complex to do as filters?

Comment: It's simply to long to use it in filter. I am checking several columns for values and do multiple boolean operations. Main problem seems to be passing MyObject to that function. I am not sure, but it seems to be using MyObject as class in general, not iterating by it, as it have place in case of MyObject.id for example.

Comment: This is what hybrid_method/hybrid_property is for.

Answer (score 27):

As I said in my comment, `hybrid_method`/`hybrid_property` is the appropriate pattern for your use case. It may at first seem complicated, but it's actually quite simple. The first version of the function operates exactly like a Python method or property, and the second part acts as a class method. SQLAlchemy filters work on the class to generate SQL.

This is just a useless example, but instead of `therabouts` your example could have a complicated calculation.

If you **don't need to pass any parameters** then I suggest using `hybrid_property` instead.

```
class MyObject(Model):
  name = Column(String)
  num = Column(Integer)

  @hybrid_method
  def therabouts(self, n):
     return self.num > n - 5 and self.num <= n + 5

  @therabouts.expression
  def therabouts(cls, n):
     return and_(cls.num > n - 5, cls.num <= n + 5)

  @hybrid_property
  def is_al(self):
     return self.name.lower().startswith('al')

  @is_al.expression
  def is_al(cls):
     return cls.name.ilike('al%')

# When used as a class method @thereabouts.expression is called
near20 = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.therabouts(20)).first()

# When used as an instance, @hybrid_method is called
near20.therabouts(20) # True
near20.therabouts(22) # Maybe True
near20.therabouts(50) # False

# filter example (class)
all_als = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.is_al).all()
for al in all_als:
  print al.name
# output Alan, Alanzo, Albert...

# instance example (self)
bob = MyObject(name='Robert')
print bob.is_al # False
```

Comment: That's fascinating, I didn't know about the `hybrid` extension. For anyone looking for it, [here's the relevant documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).

Comment: Be wary of identity checks in hybrid_properties, such as `return self.parent_id is None`. These will not behave as expected. Instead, use equality checks: `return self.parent_id == None`. I presume this behavior could be because (1) there is no exact representation of "None" in SQL language - "NULL" is the equivalent - and (2) `is` checks whether two objects reference the same location in memory, and database entries are kept on disk, not in memory. But perhaps someone else knows the reason for this with more certainty.

Comment: @NathanielJones the `@hybrid.property` construct comes in pairs. The `@hybrid_property` half operates on self and thus is just python running against the python object in memory (it sounds like you may have misdiagnosed a different error or you meant to say `cls`) .. the expression following the property such as `@myproperty.expression` uses sqlalchemy and thus you should use `cls.parent_id.is_(None)` in the expression and stick with `self.parent_id is None` in the `@hybrid_property`

Answer (score 2):

If by "use a function" you mean write the filters inside a function, you certainly can - you just need to pass the correct argument to it (the *query*) and use its return (the filtered query) in the proper place

Let's take an example from SQLAlchemy's tutorial:

```
wendy = session.query(User).filter_by(name='wendy').one()
```

You can move the filter(s) to a function easily:

```
def my_filter(query):
    return query.filter_by(name='wendy')

wendy = my_filter(session.query(User)).one()
```

---

However, if by " function that checks an object for some properties and returns boolean values depending on the result" you mean a function that accepts a *database record* as an argument, I don't think it can be done (without subverting the whole purpose of using SQL).

**--EDIT--** As `doog abides` points out, the `hybrid` extension, while not operating on database records, does something that's equivalent for many practical purposes.

---

Of course, some people will insist in writing something like:

```
all_users = session.query(User).all()
wendy= filter( lambda u:u.name=='wendy', all_users )
```

But, for the sake of the sanity of your fellow programmers and users, please don't do that.